# how to define a crypto library for xmlsec

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, xmlsec

I want to write XML signature verification code in C using any available open source libraries.I am trying to use xmlsec. I installed the dependency libraries mentioned in http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html. but when I try to compile the example code given in http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-notes-verify-x509.html , I am getting an error

"./xmlsec/crypto.h:61:2: error: #error No crypto library defined".

I am trying to compile it in ubuntu using gcc.

Could someone point how to define the crptolibrary(in this case I want to use openssl).
I installed openssl using "./configure make makeinstall" commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at xmlsec/crypto.h, it is expecting a #define or -D argument specifying what crypto library to use while building your application. If you want to use openssl, then you need to have XMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL defined somewhere.